# October CMS update data in real time

Tags: php, websocket, real-time, long-polling, octobercms

Is there some plugin for October CMS that allows to update data in different fields on site in real time? May be there is some october ajax api or class wherein it is implemented depending on DB change event?
For example I need to update fields in my plugin managment panel if someone else at this time made a change.
Unfortunately, link to the [Real time chat plugin](https://octobercms.com/forum/post/real-time-chat-plugin) does not work.
But I don't need chat solution in my case. I would not want to remodel it. Just need to mark fileds that should be updated if there were some changes in DB relative to them. It would be great if it was implemented in a simple way. Otherwise I have to implement some long-polling/websocket api/class.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this I'd recommend to use [Pusher](http://pusher.com) They got good free plan. The steps to implement would be:

1. Creating pusher instance

   ```
   window.pusher = new Pusher('APIKEY', {
       cluster: 'eu',//some problems reported about eu cluster sometimes
       authEndpoint: '/pusher/auth'
   });
   ```
2. Creating private channel wich will notify you about changes.

   ```
   var channel = window.pusher.subscribe('private-notify');
   ```
3. Subscribing to that channel. Here will go update function to change any your interface.

   ```
   channel.bind('client-messagesent', function(data) {
      //change your interface
   });
   ```
4. Pushing info from backend about changes by other users to the same channel triggering the event to call function from (3).

   ```
   $pusher->trigger('private-notify', 'client-messagesent', $data);
   ```

To start you will need include one CDN pusher script. Plenty tutorials here https://pusher.com/tutorials

There is also Pusher plugin for OctoberCMS but I ended setting pusher from scratch because that plusign adds a lot of redundant things.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Yes, this is pretty simple solution as well as firebase or some other third-party realtime data service. But I would like to use built-in tools and own database and I think that this is more correct approach. In my opinion the easiest way is to extend october's ajax api and implement long-polling method (my choice). More complex option - is to bring together october and some websocket framework such as ratchet. It would be great if devs took care of this in advance.

Comment: I would be glad to find out more approaches to this problem as well. If you'll implement some better method post please here some notes. Thanks in advance)